# Can the value of log_prob.exp() exceed 1?

Tags: python

```
def reconstructed_probability(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    """
    Computes the probability density of the input samples under the learned
    distribution of reconstructed data.
    Args:
    x: Input data tensor of shape (batch_size, num_features).
    Returns:
    A tensor of shape (batch_size,) containing the probability densities of
    the input samples under the learned distribution of reconstructed data.
    """
    with torch.no_grad():
    pred = self.predict(x)
    recon_dist = Normal(pred['recon_mu'], pred['recon_sigma'])
    x = x.unsqueeze(0)
    print(pred['recon_mu'])
    print(pred['recon_sigma'])
    p = recon_dist.log_prob(x).exp().mean(dim=0).mean(dim=-1)  # vector of shape [batch_size]
    return p
```

For example, when

```
pred['recon_mu'] = torch.tensor([[[-3.4496e-02,  6.8990e-04,  2.6068e-02],[-1.6106e-02,  9.0834e-05,  2.5933e-02],[ 1.5478e-02, -1.0349e-02,  5.4951e-03],[ 4.3387e-03, -7.6342e-03, -6.9675e-03],[-1.1998e-02,  8.4998e-03,  9.7759e-04],[-8.3179e-03,  1.9121e-02, -2.9490e-02],[-2.2698e-02, -2.6095e-03, -2.8768e-02],[ 2.1862e-02,  4.6313e-03, -3.8202e-03],[-8.9038e-03, -6.5506e-03, -2.0708e-02],[ 3.4313e-03,  3.4495e-03, -3.2643e-03],[ 2.6851e-02,  2.2717e-03, -1.5377e-02],[ 1.8616e-02,  9.1497e-03, -1.2855e-02],[ 2.6439e-02,  2.0135e-02, -1.1923e-02],[ 1.7019e-02,  1.5564e-02, -1.6765e-02],[ 3.1842e-02,  1.9835e-02, -2.1093e-02],[ 2.8283e-02,  6.9692e-03,  2.7520e-02],[-3.7459e-02,  7.6441e-03,  7.5181e-03],[-2.4621e-02, -3.1863e-03, -1.5638e-02],[ 5.9735e-03,  1.2214e-02,  1.9666e-03],[ 2.5512e-02,  8.0318e-03,  1.1243e-02],[-3.1942e-02, -6.4672e-03,  3.7776e-03],[-1.1698e-02, -6.0982e-03, -6.1742e-03],[-3.3454e-02, -5.9270e-03,  5.0409e-03],[ 1.4640e-02,  7.8550e-03,  1.4246e-03],[ 8.3495e-03,  1.4253e-02, -3.1341e-02],[ 1.7591e-03,  1.0684e-02,  2.1749e-02],[ 3.3377e-02, -7.6833e-03,  9.6476e-03],[ 7.5541e-04,  5.7854e-04,  5.8191e-03],[ 1.6344e-02,  9.8728e-03,  4.5916e-03],[-6.3240e-03,  1.2885e-02, -1.6636e-02],[ 7.3146e-03,  1.0790e-02,  1.2983e-02],[-5.3678e-02,  3.5973e-03,  1.0571e-02]]])
```

and

```
pred['recon_sigma'] = torch.tensor([[[0.0560, 0.0183, 0.0262],[0.0772, 0.0272, 0.0386],[0.0513, 0.0143, 0.0225],[0.0559, 0.0163, 0.0242],[0.0496, 0.0144, 0.0211],[0.0351, 0.0087, 0.0141],[0.0281, 0.0060, 0.0103],[0.0582, 0.0179, 0.0251],[0.0572, 0.0174, 0.0258],[0.0940, 0.0359, 0.0481],[0.0503, 0.0132, 0.0197],[0.0968, 0.0390, 0.0491],[0.0406, 0.0102, 0.0160],[0.0844, 0.0293, 0.0393],[0.0815, 0.0293, 0.0371],[0.0448, 0.0113, 0.0204],[0.0699, 0.0232, 0.0318],[0.0546, 0.0168, 0.0241],[0.0452, 0.0138, 0.0205],[0.0798, 0.0303, 0.0396],[0.0610, 0.0196, 0.0297],[0.0722, 0.0220, 0.0330],[0.0483, 0.0143, 0.0211],[0.0699, 0.0243, 0.0339],[0.0391, 0.0098, 0.0154],[0.0586, 0.0194, 0.0247],[0.0433, 0.0103, 0.0165],[0.0630, 0.0190, 0.0283],[0.0597, 0.0193, 0.0281],[0.0577, 0.0192, 0.0257],[0.0610, 0.0215, 0.0304],[0.0445, 0.0125, 0.0197]]])
```

The output p is over 1.

Is there something wrong with my code? or can the value of log_prob.exp() exceed 1?

I can't understand the reason.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine, but I guess your underlying assumption is wrong.

### Discrete case

If `recon_dist` was a *discrete* probability distribution, then `recon_dist.log_prob().exp()` would give you the values of its *probability mass function*. The values of a probability mass function all need to be greater than or equal to zero and they need to *sum to one*, which implies that each value must be smaller than or equal to one.

### Continuous case

In your case, however, `recon_dist` is a *continuous* probability distribution (namely, the normal distribution), so `recon_dist.log_prob().exp()` gives you the values of its *probability density function*. The values of a probability density function, again, all need to be greater than or equal to zero. What is different is that they need to *integrate to one* (meaning the area under the function must be one). In a situation where you have small standard deviations (like the `recon_sigma` values < 0.1 in your example), the normal distribution's peak is quite narrow, so it has to be quite high in order to reach an integral/area of one. If you look at the graph of the normal distribution's probability density function for cases with a small standard deviation (e.g. [here with a standard deviation of 0.1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20pdf%20of%20normal%20distribution%20with%20mu%3D0%20and%20sigma%3D0.1)), you can convince yourself of the fact that its peak can get greater than 1 easily – in fact, it can get arbitrarily high for arbitrarily small standard deviations.

#### Example

As an example from your data: Let's construct a normal distribution from the first given mean (-3.4496e-02) and standard deviation (0.0560), and let our values in `x` be close to the given mean value: this means we will evaluate our density function close to its narrow, high peak, which, on average, will give us a value > 1:

```py
import torch
from torch.distributions import Normal

mu = -3.4496e-02
sigma = 0.056
dist = Normal(mu, sigma)
x = torch.tensor([mu - sigma, mu, mu + sigma])

dist.log_prob(x).exp().mean().item()
# >>> 1.3518584966659546
```